# Firebase Crashlytics not working in Android Library Module (sub-project)

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I am working on a project that contains multiple Java modules. Implementing new Firebase Crashlytics went fine with main Application module, and I get crash reports in Firebase console, but I can't get it to work with these other library modules. The only thing similar to the problem I have is in [this](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#set-up-a-library-subproject) Fabric docs link, but even dough Google bought them, it doesn't work with Firebase version of Crashlytics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like all other Firebase SDKs, Firebase Crashlytics depends on a Firebase configuration that can only be applied to your application module.  You can't apply Firebase configuration to a library module.  You can put the Crashlytics dependency in a library module, but you still need to configure the app module so the SDK knows where to report the errors it captures.  This involves google-services.json and applying the fabric.io plugin, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).